# SQL query to exclude some records from the output

Tags: sql, vertica

I have a query:

```
SELECT 
       c.device_item_id
     , DATEDIFF(day, (DATE(c.tstmp)), sysdate) AS day
     , (DATE(c.tstmp)) AS date
     , COUNT(c.val) AS count
FROM (
  SELECT 
      b.device_item_id
    , TO_TIMESTAMPTZ(a.tstamp) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS tstmp
    , MAX(a.im_utilization) AS val
    FROM physical_memstats_rate AS a
    INNER JOIN v_poll_item AS b ON a.item_id = b.item_id
    WHERE b.device_item_id IN (
        SELECT item_id
        FROM v_poll_item
        WHERE device_item_id IN (
            SELECT member_item_id
            FROM etl_group_membership
            WHERE group_item_id = 335640
            )
        )
    AND a.tstamp > 1624233600 AND a.tstamp <= 1623801599
    GROUP BY 1, 2 ORDER BY 1, 2 DESC
    ) AS c
WHERE c.val > 48
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
HAVING COUNT(c.val) > 12
ORDER BY 3, 1 DESC;
```

The result of this query is:

```
device_item_id | day | date       | count
==========================================
332191         | 7   | 2021-06-17 | 287
298711         | 7   | 2021-06-17 | 104
117722         | 7   | 2021-06-17 | 287
104151         | 7   | 2021-06-17 | 287
5316           | 7   | 2021-06-17 | 287
332191         | 6   | 2021-06-18 | 288
117722         | 6   | 2021-06-18 | 288
104151         | 6   | 2021-06-18 | 288
5316           | 6   | 2021-06-18 | 288
332191         | 5   | 2021-06-19 | 288
```

I want to narrow down this result to exclude the results where the count(device_item_id) < 2 (meaning it will exclude device_item_id = 298711) but still be able to select all other columns in the output.

I tried using EXCEPT but that makes me repeat the entire query again.

Please can someone suggest how to achieve it in simplest possible way?

Thanks

Comment: Corrected my question, sorry for that. I mean to include all device_item_ids if they appear more than twice in the output yet select all the fields above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery or CTE:

```
with t as (
      <your query here>
     )
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             count(*) over (partition by device_item_id) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt >= 2;
```

Comment: Thank you so very much. Really appreciate it. This worked like charm!!!