# Writing single SQL query satisfying two cases

Tags: sql, vertica

After the comments received, I am rephrasing this question with required data.

Reference: [SQL query to exclude some records from the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68123522/sql-query-to-exclude-some-records-from-the-output/68123590#68123590)

Vertica analytical functions: https://www.vertica.com/blog/analytic-queries-vertica/

Table 1:

```
create table etl_group_membership
(
    group_item_id int not null,
    member_item_id int not null
);

INSERT INTO etl_group_membership (group_item_id, member_item_id) VALUES (335640, 117722);
INSERT INTO etl_group_membership (group_item_id, member_item_id) VALUES (335640, 104151);
INSERT INTO etl_group_membership (group_item_id, member_item_id) VALUES (335640, 5316);

INSERT INTO etl_group_membership (group_item_id, member_item_id) VALUES (335641, 117723);
INSERT INTO etl_group_membership (group_item_id, member_item_id) VALUES (335641, 104152);
INSERT INTO etl_group_membership (group_item_id, member_item_id) VALUES (335641, 5317);

INSERT INTO etl_group_membership (group_item_id, member_item_id) VALUES (335642, 117724);
INSERT INTO etl_group_membership (group_item_id, member_item_id) VALUES (335642, 104153);
INSERT INTO etl_group_membership (group_item_id, member_item_id) VALUES (335642, 5318);
```

Table 2:

```
create table v_poll_item
(
    device_item_id int not null,
    item_id int not null
    
);

INSERT INTO v_poll_item (device_item_id, item_id) VALUES (117722, 273215);
INSERT INTO v_poll_item (device_item_id, item_id) VALUES (117722, 117936);
INSERT INTO v_poll_item (device_item_id, item_id) VALUES (117722, 117873);
INSERT INTO v_poll_item (device_item_id, item_id) VALUES (117722, 123305);

INSERT INTO v_poll_item (device_item_id, item_id) VALUES (104151, 240006);
INSERT INTO v_poll_item (device_item_id, item_id) VALUES (104151, 240005);
INSERT INTO v_poll_item (device_item_id, item_id) VALUES (104151, 239415);
INSERT INTO v_poll_item (device_item_id, item_id) VALUES (104151, 239414);

INSERT INTO v_poll_item (device_item_id, item_id) VALUES (5316, 118310);
INSERT INTO v_poll_item (device_item_id, item_id) VALUES (5316, 130627);
INSERT INTO v_poll_item (device_item_id, item_id) VALUES (5316, 298564);
INSERT INTO v_poll_item (device_item_id, item_id) VALUES (5316, 118311);
```

Table 3: **Note** that im_utilization can be NULL as well

```
create table nrm_cpustats_rate
(
    item_id int not null,
    tstamp datetime not null,
    im_utilization float,
);

INSERT INTO nrm_cpustats_rate (item_id, tstamp, im_utilization) VALUES (273215, '2021-06-28 19:55:00.000000', 2);
INSERT INTO nrm_cpustats_rate (item_id, tstamp, im_utilization) VALUES (273215, '2021-06-27 23:35:00.000000', 24);
INSERT INTO nrm_cpustats_rate (item_id, tstamp, im_utilization) VALUES (273215, '2021-06-26 14:05:00.000000', 27);
INSERT INTO nrm_cpustats_rate (item_id, tstamp, im_utilization) VALUES (273215, '2021-06-25 09:05:00.000000', 29);

INSERT INTO nrm_cpustats_rate (item_id, tstamp, im_utilization) VALUES (117936, '2021-06-28 19:30:00.000000', 17);
INSERT INTO nrm_cpustats_rate (item_id, tstamp, im_utilization) VALUES (117936, '2021-06-28 19:15:00.000000', 35);
INSERT INTO nrm_cpustats_rate (item_id, tstamp, im_utilization) VALUES (117936, '2021-06-28 19:05:00.000000', 50);
INSERT INTO nrm_cpustats_rate (item_id, tstamp, im_utilization) VALUES (117936, '2021-06-27 05:45:00.000000', 89);
INSERT INTO nrm_cpustats_rate (item_id, tstamp, im_utilization) VALUES (117936, '2021-06-25 09:20:00.000000', 37);
INSERT INTO nrm_cpustats_rate (item_id, tstamp, im_utilization) VALUES (117936, '2021-06-25 09:10:00.000000', 51);
INSERT INTO nrm_cpustats_rate (item_id, tstamp, im_utilization) VALUES (117936, '2021-06-25 08:50:00.000000', 90);

INSERT INTO nrm_cpustats_rate (item_id, tstamp, im_utilization) VALUES (118310, '2021-06-23 04:10:00.000000', 51);
INSERT INTO nrm_cpustats_rate (item_id, tstamp, im_utilization) VALUES (118310, '2021-06-23 03:15:00.000000', 48);
INSERT INTO nrm_cpustats_rate (item_id, tstamp, im_utilization) VALUES (118310, '2021-06-22 22:20:00.000000', 19);

INSERT INTO nrm_cpustats_rate (item_id, tstamp, im_utilization) VALUES (239414, '2021-06-22 17:10:00.000000', 11);
INSERT INTO nrm_cpustats_rate (item_id, tstamp, im_utilization) VALUES (239414, '2021-06-22 16:30:00.000000', 37);
INSERT INTO nrm_cpustats_rate (item_id, tstamp, im_utilization) VALUES (239414, '2021-06-22 16:35:00.000000', 38);
INSERT INTO nrm_cpustats_rate (item_id, tstamp, im_utilization) VALUES (239414, '2021-06-28 18:45:00.000000', 74);
INSERT INTO nrm_cpustats_rate (item_id, tstamp, im_utilization) VALUES (239414, '2021-06-28 18:48:00.000000', 76);
INSERT INTO nrm_cpustats_rate (item_id, tstamp, im_utilization) VALUES (239414, '2021-06-28 18:50:00.000000', 77);

INSERT INTO nrm_cpustats_rate (item_id, tstamp, im_utilization) VALUES (118311, '2021-06-28 00:40:00.000000', 29);
INSERT INTO nrm_cpustats_rate (item_id, tstamp, im_utilization) VALUES (118311, '2021-06-23 22:30:00.000000', 37);
INSERT INTO nrm_cpustats_rate (item_id, tstamp, im_utilization) VALUES (118311, '2021-06-23 22:25:00.000000', 92);
```

To get the device items ids in a group:

`SELECT member_item_id FROM etl_group_membership WHERE group_item_id = 335640;`

From the list of device item ids retrieved, to get the list of item_ids:

`SELECT item_id FROM v_poll_item WHERE device_item_id IN (<devices retrieved from previous query>);`

## Inputs:

1. Two time ranges: yesterday until 7 days back (`AND tstamp > '2021-06-22 00:00:00.000000'AND tstamp <= '2021-06-28 23:59:59.000000'`)
2. Group id: 335640
3. breach_threshold: 25
4. Minimum number of breaches each day: 2

## Expected output:

breached means im_utilization is >= 25

Pick only those records where count_of_breached in a given day >= 2
That is, records with item_id 273215 are excluded because even though the number of breaches (>= 25) are 2, there's only one each day

```
device_item_id  |  item_id  |  count_of_breach  |  date_when_breached  |  max_utilization  |  max_utilization_tstamp
=====================================================================================================================
117722          |  117936   |  2                |  2021-06-28          | 90                |  2021-06-25 08:50:00.000000
117722          |  117936   |  3                |  2021-06-25          | 90                |  2021-06-25 08:50:00.000000
5316            |  118310   |  2                |  2021-06-23          | 51                |  2021-06-23 04:10:00.000000
5316            |  118311   |  2                |  2021-06-23          | 92                |  2021-06-23 22:25:00.000000
104151          |  239414   |  2                |  2021-06-22          | 77                |  2021-06-28 18:50:00.000000
104151          |  239414   |  3                |  2021-06-28          | 77                |  2021-06-28 18:50:00.000000
```

Even if a single SQL query cannot be written to produce this output, can two optimized queries be suggested. @marcothesane pointed that even the [query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68123522/sql-query-to-exclude-some-records-from-the-output/68123590#68123590) to get daily breaches can be written in a better way.

## UPDATE:

This query has worked for me for finding the max im_utlization and tstamp when it was max. I am not sure though why I had to use the timestamp range at two places!

```
SELECT t.item_id, t.tstamp, t.im_utilization
FROM (
    SELECT item_id, MAX(im_utilization) AS max_cpu
    FROM nrm_cpustats_rate
    WHERE item_id IN (SELECT item_id from v_poll_item WHERE device_item_id IN (SELECT item_id FROM v_poll_item WHERE device_item_id IN (117722, 104151, 5316)))
    AND tstamp > '2021-06-22 00:00:00.000000
    AND tstamp <= '2021-06-28 23:59:59.000000'
    GROUP BY item_id
) AS m
INNER JOIN nrm_cpustats_rate AS t
ON t.item_id = m.item_id
AND t.im_utilization = m.max_cpu
AND tstamp > '2021-06-22 00:00:00.000000
AND tstamp <= '2021-06-28 23:59:59.000000'
ORDER BY 1, 2 DESC, 3 DESC
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the appropriate DBMS. I see a lot of invalid syntax for SQL Server.

Comment: I tagged it. But I think if we take out date/time related functions, it should be the same syntax for SQL Server as well.

Comment: I'm almost sure you can simplify your initial query more than what you came up with. But I can't try, as you don't supply input data. How do you get a `max` of 20,17 and 19 respectively? Can you paste a bunch of rows from an intermediate result? I think that a few clever uses of OLAP functions can help. But I can't try this way ...

Comment: I edited the question to make the problem statement more verbose. Please see if this makes sense now.

Comment: Please supply create statements for the tables, insert statements for sufficient data to illustrate the requirement and desired output.

Answer (score 0):

To start, all your preliminary work relies specifically with the cpustats rate table.  But as you mentioned, the breach consideration is based on more than 1 (hence 2 or more) ON THE SAME DAY.  So, on a per item, per day (hence date( ncr.tstamp ) field to get just the DATE portion regardless of time, we can apply a HAVING clause so only those when grouped by item and date have more than one breach.

Then, from that, we can join to the poll item table for the specific device ID.  The following should work for you.

```
select 
        vpi.device_item_id,
        ncr.item_id,
        count(*) count_of_breach,
        date( ncr.tstamp ) date_when_breached,
        max( ncr.im_utilization ) max_utilization
    from
        nrm_cpustats_rate ncr
            join v_poll_item vpi
                on ncr.item_id = vpi.item_id
    where
        ncr.im_utilization >= 25
    group by
        vpi.device_item_id,
        ncr.item_id,
        date( ncr.tstamp )
    having
        count(*) > 1
```

**FEEDBACK - MODIFICATION**

Removed the second table from query and trying with the TRUNC() function within query instead of date().  Also added in your date filter restriction.

```
select 
        ncr.item_id,
        count(*) count_of_breach,
        trunc( ncr.tstamp, 'DD' ) date_when_breached,
        max( ncr.im_utilization ) max_utilization
    from
        nrm_cpustats_rate ncr
    where
            ncr.tstamp > '2021-06-22 00:00:00.000000'
        AND ncr.tstamp <= '2021-06-28 23:59:59.000000'
        AND ncr.im_utilization >= 25
    group by
        ncr.item_id,
        trunc( ncr.tstamp, 'DD' )
    having
        count(*) > 1
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work! It first gives an error that ```vpi.device_item_id``` should be part of ```GROUP BY``` and then produces no records when two inout dates are supplied ```AND TO_TIMESTAMPTZ(tstamp) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'  > TRUNC(sysdate - 7)
AND TO_TIMESTAMPTZ(tstamp) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' <= TRUNC(sysdate - 1) + 1 - INTERVAL '1 SECOND'``` The input dates are from 7 days back until yesterday.

Comment: @RajnishJain, sorry, forgot to add the new column when pulling the device_item_id.  Should be good.  Since I don't have/use vertica-SQL, not positive of the date() function working.  I THINK it should, if not, it may need to be changed to your TRUNC() function to truncate the time portion of a date/time stamp field.

Comment: Even without using any timestamp range, the query suggested by you doesn't produce any result. I edited the question to remove any Vertica specific dat/time functions and supplied two input timestamps as datetime.

Comment: @RajnishJain, revised answer and changed to trunc(),  Try the second query first, then pull the part with the JOIN second table back into it.

Answer (score 0):

You can hard-cast a TIMESTAMP to a DATE with the `::DATE` operation.

As the others did it:

You can get all the first five columns in a grouping query, grouping by `device_item_id,v_poll_item.item_id,tstamp::DATE` . I put that as a common Table Expression (CTE) into a WITH clause. Then, I joined that CTE back with `nrm_cpustats_rate` over `item_id` and an equi predicate over the previously obtained `max_utilization` and `im_utilization`; and I finally filter away the rows with less than 2 breach counts and filter again by the timestamp range.

```
WITH
grp AS (
  SELECT
    device_item_id
  , v_poll_item.item_id
  , SUM(
      CASE 
        WHEN im_utilization >= 25 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
      END 
    ) AS count_of_breach
  , tstamp::DATE as date_when_breached
  , MAX(im_utilization) AS max_utilization
  FROM nrm_cpustats_rate
  JOIN v_poll_item USING(item_id)
  JOIN etl_group_membership ON member_item_id=device_item_id
  WHERE  tstamp > '2021-06-22 00:00:00.000000'AND tstamp <= '2021-06-28 23:59:59.000000'
  GROUP BY
    device_item_id
  , v_poll_item.item_id
  , tstamp::DATE
)
SELECT
  grp.*
, o.tstamp AS max_utilization_tstamp
FROM grp 
JOIN nrm_cpustats_rate o 
  ON o.item_id=grp.item_id 
 AND max_utilization=im_utilization
WHERE  tstamp > '2021-06-22 00:00:00.000000'AND tstamp <= '2021-06-28 23:59:59.000000'
  AND count_of_breach >= 2
;
-- out  device_item_id | item_id | count_of_breach | date_when_breached | max_utilization | max_utilization_tstamp 
-- out ----------------+---------+-----------------+--------------------+-----------------+------------------------
-- out            5316 |  118310 |               2 | 2021-06-23         |              51 | 2021-06-23 04:10:00
-- out          104151 |  239414 |               3 | 2021-06-28         |              77 | 2021-06-28 18:50:00
-- out          104151 |  239414 |               2 | 2021-06-22         |              38 | 2021-06-22 16:35:00
-- out          117722 |  117936 |               3 | 2021-06-25         |              90 | 2021-06-25 08:50:00
-- out            5316 |  118311 |               2 | 2021-06-23         |              92 | 2021-06-23 22:25:00
-- out          117722 |  117936 |               2 | 2021-06-28         |              50 | 2021-06-28 19:05:00
```

Comment: Did you create a different data set than what I provided in INSERT statements? If not, then the outputs do not match. I am trying this in my development database where the number of records are much higher. I will update here if this worked. However, many thanks for taking time out to look into this. I really liked the way you calculated "count_of_breach"!!!

Comment: No - I used exactly the data you provided - just ran the CREATE TABLER and INSERT statements against my Vertica database ...

Comment: If you didn't change the data set, then isn't the output unexpected? Also, how can this be possible to not check against every ```member_item_id``` in ```etc_group_membership``` table? That is, as mentioned in the question above, we will get one single ```group_item_id``` as input and then have to retrieve list of ```device_item_id``` from there and then list of ```item_id``` from there. Please see the lines just above Inputs section above. I am sorry but I am not good at SQLs and therefore seeking help.

Comment: The only difference I found is that you have twice a max_utilization of 90 for device_item_id  117722, while I have 90 and 50, and you have twice 77 for device_item_id 104151, while I have 77 and 38. And I think that my result is closer to the input data ....

Comment: Thank you. The reason I have multiple same values of max is that I repeated the max value/tstamp found. I felt that if we have to get everything in the same query then the max will repeat for the same item id since there can be only one max value. Is it also possible to adjust the query with what I mentioned in my previous comment?